# Concatenating two vectors of unequal lengths in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Assume that you have two vectors named A and B of different lengths. Create a vector C that
combines A and B in a manner similar to part a. However, if you run out of elements in one of
the vectors, C also contains the elements remaining from the longer vector. For instance, if A
has length m and B has length n where n>m, C = [A (1) B (1) A (2) B (2) ... A(m) B(m) B(m+1)
B(m+2) … B(n)]

for two vectors of equal length I have:

a = 0:2:10

b = 1:2:11

c= [a;b]

c= c(:)'

Is there a simple way of doing this for unequal vector lengths? Solutions I found on Chegg are convoluted.

Comment: `in a manner similar to part a.` So how did you do part a?

Answer (score 0):

Does this count as simple?

```
s = min(numel(a), numel(b)); % minimum of the two lengths
c = [reshape([a(1:s); b(1:s)], 1, []), a(s+1:end), b(s+1:end)];
```

It uses your approach for the minimum of the two lengths and then concatenates the remainder of the two vectors; but there will be at most only *one* non-empty remainder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is homework, so I'll provide you with a simple step-by-step solution instead of a code:

1. Pad `a` with as many `inf`'s as you need to make it equal length as `b`. (Indexing using `end+1` and `numel(b)` can be useful here)
2. Concatenate the two horizontal vectors below each other, and create a vertical vector using `(:)`.
3. Remove all `inf`-values from the result.

Note: Luis' solution is cleaner, but you might have a hard time explaining what is going on if you are asked questions.